# C# Linq adding to dictionary with list as value

Tags: c#, linq

I have a dictionary like this:

```
Dictionary<string, List<myobject>>
```

As I am getting new items, I'm doing logic like this:

```
mydictionary[key].add(mynewobject);
```

now, I'm trying to do the same with LINQ, but I'm stuck on the last line:
(please ignore the bit of irrelevant logic in the code):

```
var Test =
    (from F in Directory.EnumerateFiles(SOURCE_FOLDER, SOURCE_EXTENSIONS, SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    let Key = ParenthesisGroupRegex.Replace(F.ToLower(), string.Empty).Trim()
    let Descriptions =
        (from Match Match in ParenthesisGroupRegex.Matches(F.ToLower())
        let CleanedMatches = ParenthesisRegex.Replace(Match.Name, string.Empty)
        let MatchesList = CleanedMatches.Split(',')
        select new Description { Filename = F, Tag = MatchesList.ToList() })
    group Descriptions by Key into DescriptionList
    select new KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<string>>(Key, DescriptionList))
```

If we look at the last two lines:
I'm trying to get my List (List

and on the last linne, I'm attempting to build dictionary entries, but this will not compile as it looks like neither Key, nor DescriptionList, are accessible at that stage.

(btw, I'm currently learning the LINQ syntax, so readability and maintainability are not the focus right now)

What did I miss?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could call the `ToDictionary` at the end of the query you have defined:

```
var Test =
(from F in Directory.EnumerateFiles(SOURCE_FOLDER, SOURCE_EXTENSIONS, SearchOption.AllDirectories)
let Key = ParenthesisGroupRegex.Replace(F.ToLower(), string.Empty).Trim()
let Descriptions =
    (from Match Match in ParenthesisGroupRegex.Matches(F.ToLower())
    let CleanedMatches = ParenthesisRegex.Replace(Match.Name, string.Empty)
    let MatchesList = CleanedMatches.Split(',')
    select new Description { Filename = F, Tag = MatchesList.ToList() })
group Descriptions by Key)
.ToDictionary(x=>x.Key,x=>x.ToList());
```

Essentially `GroupBy` as it stated [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534304(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Groups the elements of a sequence according to a specified key
>   selector function and projects the elements for each group by using a
>   specified function.

and it's signature is the following:

```
public static IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TElement>> GroupBy<TSource, TKey, TElement>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector,
    Func<TSource, TElement> elementSelector
)
```

Note that the return type of `GroupBy` is this

```
IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TElement>>
```

The above type essentially declares a sequence of keys and collections of objects that are associated with these keys (More formally it declares a sequence of objects of type `IGrouping<TKey, TElement>`, where [IGrouping](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb344977(v=vs.110).aspx) represents a collection of objects that have a common key.). That you want is a dicitonary with the keys in this sequence and values the corresponding collection of objects. This can be achieved as above by calling the [ToDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549277(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

Comment: This will not compile: "A query body must end with a select clause or a group clause"

Comment: but thanks a lot for the information, I am starting to understand better how group operates

Comment: @Thomas You are very welcome. Please try the updated query. Essentially I removed the `into`, which is used to specify a temporary identifier in order to continue your query and make further operation based on this identifier, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/group-clause